# Magento 2 : how to convert custom quote field to order field

Tags: magento2, quote, custom-field, convert

I added a new field "**management_fee**" on table "quote" properly. I add this field on "**sales_order**" field too. 
I would like to update this field on sales_order table while quote is converting to order.

I know how to do with quote items using plugin and `Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\ToOrderItem` class, but I did not find a class for quote to order.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

add the fields to both table `quote` and  `sales_order` via a setup script in your module.

Then add an event in your module (see below)

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
        <event name="sales_model_service_quote_submit_before">
            <observer name="quote_submit_before" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\QuoteSubmitBefore" />
        </event>
    </config>
```

Finally save the quote data against your order

```
class QuoteSubmitBefore implements ObserverInterface
{

    /**
     * @param Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
       $quote = $observer->getQuote();
       $order = $observer->getOrder();

       $order->setData('field_custom', $quote->getData('field_custom'));      
    }
}
```

Comment: Still the only working way to do this even with 2.4 :/

Answer (score 1):

I am not really aware of this thing but you can give a try I hope it'll work for you. Create a fieldset.xml in your module's etc folder.

**fieldset.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:DataObject/etc/fieldset.xsd">
    <scope id="global">
        <fieldset id="sales_convert_quote">
            <field name="management_fee">
              <aspect name="to_order" />
           </field>
        </fieldset>
    </scope>
</config>
```

You should check below link as well    https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/ext-best-practices/tutorials/copy-fieldsets.html

Comment: It does not work.

Comment: have you tried it with the link?

Comment: have you tried it with the link

Comment: IT DOES NOT WORK